# Tools and algorithms for finding non-verbatim quotations

Tags: computational-linguistics, corpora

I have a textual corpus consisting of about 500 different texts, written in the time span of several centuries. The authors of these texts belonged to the same culture, so they used to read and cite each other. So, I want to be able to find all the quotations from a text (let's call it `mytext`) in the other texts of the corpus.

At first, using a naïve approach, I made a program, which took all the (overlapping) sequences of 5 (or 6, or 7) words from `mytext` and looked for these sequences in all the other texts. This algorithm works, but has certain drawbacks and raises some questions.

1. I don't know beforehand, how long my sequence should be.
2. There could be non-verbatim quotations: a word could be substituted by a synonym or simply deleted, word-order could be slightly changed etc.
3. Both `mytext` and some other text may quote a third source, sometimes outside my corpus.
4. There can be trivial quotations, e.g. idioms, etc. Moreover, there can be trivial quotations of 5 words and non-trivial ones of 3 words.

So, I am looking for some theory and known algorithms, which I could implement in my code.

Comment: You can look into collocations, where significance is essentially a higher frequency than the constituent words would predict, to solve the triviality question. Also, I suggest ignoring 3 till you identify likely quotations. For the non-verbatim question, I think there are a couple of approaches that I'll leave for someone who knows more than me to explore.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Thanks! Could you please give some more details about how to use collocations? I'm a novice, so please give me some clues.

Comment: [Bag of words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model) maybe.

Comment: The basic algorithm is: List each run of n adjacent words in a text. In a set, take word A & count its frequency, say 0.001%. Take word B & count its frequency, say 0.002%. Multiply these to find the expected probability of their appearing together: 0.000002%. Now count the whole run's frequency. If it's much higher than expected (e.g.  0.0002% or 100x higher), it's a collocation, e.g. "graph paper". For your purposes, you could then make a list of *non*-collocations, i.e. runs that are unique rather than everyday pairs. If non-collocations are found across more than one text, they are quotes.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Thanks a lot! The algorithm looks very effective, but I don't understand some details. E.g. when I check the frequencies of two words in the corpus, does that mean that I just multiply their frequencies and the distance between them is not taken into account?

Comment: @evb That's right — you're comparing them in isolation *vs.* when they're together. Though you could do more sophisticated things if the results weren't satisfying. For example, if I read you right, it might turn out that when people talk about "math", they tend to use related words, such as "operation", "sum", etc. You could then use that the same way: a nearby "operation" and "sum" with a few words in between might seem rare enough to make it onto the list of quotables, but in the context of "math" they become expected. Also, I forgot to mention that you would want to ignore stopwords.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Thanks! Can I write you a PM? I feel, I have more questions than will fit into the comments thread. :)

Comment: @evb Feel free — I don't know if I can help much more than that but I'm happy to try! You can write my first name at my last name dot ca.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use word embeddings (google word2vec) to help you do inexact matches of words. I would look for sequences of at least 4 words (4-grams) as anything shorter would be difficult to call a quote. Create a function that gives you a distance between each 4-gram and then find a value for this distance that yealds results on some examples you have.

Comment: Thanks, I feel I should get acquainted with word2vec. Unfortunately I don't know Python...

Comment: It looks like the original [word2vec](https://github.com/dav/word2vec) is written in C, but has Python bindings elsewhere on Github. You could likely find bindings to a language you know, since C is a lingua franca.

Answer (score 1):

[Vesanto et al., Applying BLAST to Text Reuse Detection in Finnish Newspapers and Journals, 1771-1910](http://www.ep.liu.se/ecp/article.asp?issue=133&article=010&volume=) successfully used BLAST, a computer program to compare proteins, for a similar task: They tracked the spread of news items in Finnish newspapers (ORCed, so many typical OCR errors were present in the electronically available texts).